# How to initialise the Bresenham algorithm to display an hyperbole

Tags: graphics, bresenham, hyperbolic-function

I have an exam in graphics informatic and I am trying to understand the Bresenham algorithm. I understand displaying a line and a circle (I think) but when I do an exercise where I have to display a hyperbolic function I can't make it right.

The hyperbolic function has the equation y = 100/x and I converted it to x*y - 100 = 0. I assume that the currently displayed pixel is at (x_p, y_p) on the screen. I calculated the increments and I found I = 2y_p - 1  when the pixel to be displayed is the one at the right, and I = 2y_p - 2x_p - 5 when the pixel to be displayed is at the bottom right. But now I don't know how to initialise. In my courses, the initialisation for a line is made at x_0 = 0, y_0 = 0, for a circle of a radius R, it is x_0 = 0, y_0 = R, but what is it for my hyperbole ?

I want to trace the hyperbole from x = 10 up to x = 20

```c
void trace (const int x1, const int y1, const int x2)
{
  int x = x1;
  int y = y1;
  int FM = //what to put here ???
  glVertex2i(x,y);

  while (x < x2)
  {
    if (FM < 0)
    {
      ++x; --y;
      const int dSE = 2*y - 2*x - 5;
      FM += dSE;
    }
    else
    {
      ++x;
      const int dE = 2*y - 1;
      FM += dE;
    }

    glVertex2i(x,y);
  }
}
```

so I called this function like that :

```c
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    trace(10,10,20);
glEnd();
```

I know it is old OpenGL, I use it just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're probably aware, the basic idea behind Bresenham-style algorithms is that you're taking a series of fixed steps, and at each step you're making a decision.  In this particular case, the steps are `x` positions between 10 and 20, and the decision is whether the next `y` value should be `y` or `y - 1`.

To make this decision, you want to pick the y value that's going to be closest to the function value for the next `x` coordinate: `100 / (x + 1)`.  So, you pick `y` if `dist(y, 100 / (x + 1))` is smaller than `dist(y - 1, 100 / (x + 1))`... otherwise, pick `y - 1`.  That decision is equivalent to deciding whether the following expression is negative:

```
err(x, y) = (y - 100 / (x + 1)) ^ 2 - (y - 1 - 100 / (x + 1)) ^ 2
          = 2 * (y - 100 / (x + 1)) - 1
          = 2 * y - 200 / (x + 1) - 1
```

Since `x + 1` is positive for the range we are interested in, we can multiply through by it to get an equivalent decision value:

```
err(x, y) = 2 * y * x + 2 * y - 200 - x - 1
          = 2 * y * x + 2 * y - x - 201
```

This is the decision value you want to use for each step, so it's also the formula you'd want to use to calculate the initial decision value.  You can then calculate `err(x + 1, y) - err(x, y)` and `err(x + 1, y - 1) - err(x, y)` to get the incremental update formulas to be used in the loop.

There are, of course, other formulas that will also work, and any given formula may need some adaption if you:

- swap the meaning of the `y` vs. `y - 1` decision
- decide to compute the decision value using the pre-update vs. post-update values of `x` and `y`
- want to draw pixels with the closest centers to the function vs. pixels with the closest coordinate

Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0e8fnk5h/

Comment: I managed to finally draw this hyperbola ty. But I have still some points I don't understand quite well. You initialized with `y = 100/10 + 1/2` and it worked but I have an example where y is initialized with `y = f(x) - 1/2` (for circles). When should I use one or the other? And also I always invert what to put when `err > 0` and `err < 0`

Comment: In JavaScript, `Math.floor()` rounds down to the next integer, so `Math.floor(x + 0.5)` always returns the nearest integer to `x`.  If you are in C/C++, coercing a float to an integer *truncates*, which means it rounds positive values down and negative values up.  So `y = f(x) - 0.5;` would give you the nearest integer in the case where `f(x)` is a negative value and `y` has an integer type.  I expect the circle code you are looking at is drawing an octant of the circle where `y` is negative.  And yeah, if you're swapping the order of the `y` and `y - 1` branches, you'd want to negate `err`.

Comment: Hey, it's been I wild since I posted this question, but thanks to your answer I managed to have 15/20 to the exam on this topic, so thanks you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The control variable `FM` has to be initialized to the distance of the first mid-point to the curve. In this case, you measure distance by twice the value of the implicit function, i.e. we have

```
FM = 2 * F(x1 + 1, y1 + 1/2)
   = 2 * [(x1 + 1) * (y1 + 1/2) - 100]
   = 2 * x1 * y1 + 2 * y1 + x1 - 199
```